# PHP - Removing part of string if certain word exist

Tags: php

I need to remove the page number on this URL string if page number exist:

*/book-list/fisica/page-9*

Result should be:

*/book-list/fisica*

Thank you for any help.

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: that is what's called a "mod rewrite".

Comment: I need to do it with php instead of mode rewrite.

Comment: And this site is for programming questions. It is not a code writing or "do my job for me" service. YOU show what you've done to attempt this, we'll (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: you could probably use `DEFINE` http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php but that's a hack and a half. Why must you use PHP for this? or even `strpos()` - `stripos()`. Edit: The former won't work since you're looking if it exists; use the latter.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
$url = '/book-list/fisica/page-9';
$remove_page = preg_replace('/\/page-[\d]*/','', $url);
```

Check here:- https://regex101.com/r/Pl41eK/2

Comment: care to explain downvote?

Comment: Not my downvote but the question looks more like they're trying to detect if something exists. Read the question again.

Comment: probably because the question is marked as duplicate, i overlooked that

Comment: It's hard to say, it could be anything. I can't see why they would even if it were a duplicate.